# Error encountered during multiple postbacks of an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, autopostback

I have made an ASP.NET web page which retrieves some data based on a date (selected using a Calendar control), and segment (selected using a dropdownlist). Changing either the date or the segment causes the page to refresh and the data to be reloaded.

Now when I run the web page using the Visual Studio server, the following things happen:

1) When I select a new date (say from X to Y), and then change the segment (say from A to B) *before* the page is refreshed, then the date remains X, and the data is retrieved for date=X and segment=B.

2) When I select a new segment (A to B), and then change the date (X to Y) *before* the page is refreshed, both get changed and the data is retrived accordingly for date=Y and segment=B.

Now, I have hosted this web page on my PC using IIS. When I do the above two operations on the web page hosted using IIS, I encounter exceptions. And if I repeat the two operations thrice, I get six different exceptions!

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the exceptions you're encountering?

Comment: One time, it might be a null object reference exception for the SqlConnection object that I am using , and another time, it might be an Exception that a parameter name that I have used in an SQL query has already been declared (variable names must be unique), even though that is not true

Comment: If You change second value before refresh, it's possible that server is processing 2 requests a the same time and that can lead to concurrency problems. How do You keep Your SqlConnection? If it's static, it's possible that one process is using it while the other try to change it. Could You provide some code behind?

Comment: Can't provide the code behind due to some reasons, but yes, the SqlConnection object is static. But then why I am not getting the same errors when I am running it on the Visual Studio test server?

Comment: It propably depends on how test server handles multiple request. Maybe someone who knows more about it can help You here. I haven't really used test server, I always have local IIS for testing. Anyway one connection in static is not a good solution, with many users it will be even more problematic(on SQL level as well). I always store connections in Session.

Comment: Without code behind it's going to be hard to help you.  Have you reviewed the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)?